# PrimeNG Listbox not showing label

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

The "rolename" label refuses to render on the  UI; I am using Angular 4/Prime NG

.html file definition

```
<p-listbox formControlName="userRole" [options]="this.userRoleItems" optionLabel="rolename" multiple="multiple" [style]='{"width":"250px"}'  checkbox="checkbox" filter="filter"
            >
          </p-listbox>
```

constructor of .ts file

```
 userRoleItems: UserRole[] = [{id: 2, rolename: 'test'}]; ;
```

userrole class definition:

```
  export class UserRole {
      id: number;
      rolename: string;
  }
```

Picture of how it is on the UI: (You see the checkbox shows but not tthe label)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same behaviour with primeng 4.1.0, the problem is related to your primeng version.
Try to upgrade to latest 4.3.0.

See the link below for a plunkr demo.

`link:`[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aXlds3bu3FDX1QgHEYdJ?p=preview)

Comment: What is the command to update prime ng to 4.3.0? i am on version   "primeng": "4.2.2",

Comment: Same bug in 4.2.1. Updating to 4.3.0 fixes the issue.